# Can I set a different border for individual items in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, colors, border, listitem

I have a custom ListView adapter that changes the background colour of the list items depending on some rules.

This is mostly working.

In 1 scenario I want to represent 2 colours in the same listitem. I thought I could do this by setting the border thickness and colour of the border, but I cannot get that to work.

Can someone tell me if this can be done and if so how.

Also, if there is another way to display 2 colours in the same listitem (say 1 colour that gradiated into the other) then I'd be happy with a different implementation.

Here is the code:

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
public ArrayList<String> listColours=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

public static final String LOGid = "TouchAndGo";

public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, items, resource, from, to);
}

public SpecialAdapter(WWFoodFinderActivity context,
        List<Map<String, String>> data, int simpleListItem2, String[] from,
        int[] to) {
    super(context, data, simpleListItem2, from,to);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = null;
  try
  {
      view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      Log.d(LOGid, "Position:" + position + "Value:" + listColours.get(position) + "Line:" + listItems.get(position));
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      Log.e(LOGid, "Failed to get handle on view " + e.getMessage());
  }

  /* This never works - cannot get a handle on the thisview this way :( */
  ListView lv = null;
  try
  {
      lv = (ListView) view;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      Log.e(LOGid, "Failed to get handle on Listview " + e.getMessage());
  }

  try
  {

      if (listColours.get(position).equals("Y"))
      {
          Log.d(LOGid, "View set to green with green border");
          view.setBackgroundColor (android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 150, 40));
          lv.setDividerHeight(2);
          ColorDrawable green = new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 150, 40));
          lv.setDivider(green);

      }
      else if (listColours.get(position).equals("C"))
      {
          Log.d(LOGid, "View set to blue with blue border");
          view.setBackgroundColor (android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 40, 150));
          lv.setDividerHeight(2);
          ColorDrawable blue = new     ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 40, 150));
          lv.setDivider(blue);

      }
      /* This is the exception case, need to represent 2 colours in the same listitem */
      else if (listColours.get(position).equals("Y/C"))
      {
          Log.d(LOGid, "View set to green with blue border");
          view.setBackgroundColor (android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 150, 40));
          lv.setDividerHeight(2);
          ColorDrawable blue = new     ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 150, 40));
          lv.setDivider(blue);
          //lv.setDivider();
//        Log.d(LOGid, "View set to green");
      }

      else
      {
          Log.d(LOGid, "View set to black with black");
          view.setBackgroundColor (android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
          lv.setDividerHeight(2);
          ColorDrawable black = new     ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
          lv.setDivider(black);

      }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      Log.e(LOGid, "Error rendering list item: " + e.getMessage());
  }
/*    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
  view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]); */ 
  return view;
}
}
```

The final step I have is that I want to set the border for some listitems individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the BaseAdapter and then in getView function:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);        
try
  {

      if (listColours.get(position).equals("Y"))
      {
          view.setBackgroundColor (android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 150, 40));
          ColorDrawable green = new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 150, 40));
      }
      else if (listColours.get(position).equals("C"))
          view.setBackgroundColor (android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 40, 150));
          ColorDrawable blue = new     ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 40, 150));
      }
      else if (listColours.get(position).equals("Y/C"))
      {
          view.setBackgroundColor (android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 150, 40));
          ColorDrawable blue = new     ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.rgb(40, 150, 40));
      }

      else
      {
          view.setBackgroundColor (android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
          ColorDrawable black = new     ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
      }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      Log.e(LOGid, "Error rendering list item: " + e.getMessage());
  }

return view;
}
```

Set up layout for items with your own divider and here change his colour. Don't forget to remove dividers form ListView.